# Strange discrete errors when reading HC-SR04 sonar sensor

Tags: sensors, hc-sr04, timing, esp32

I'm experimenting with an HC-SR04 sonar sensor. Basically I'm measuring the distance to a cardboard box twice a second with these lines of code running on an ESP32:

```
unsigned long sonarMeasure() {
    digitalWrite(TRIGGER, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(TRIGGER, LOW);
    return pulseIn(ECHO, HIGH);
}

double distance = duration * 0.03455;
```

The results are a bit strange. I know, that I can't expect millimeter accuracy. But why are there rather **discrete jumps of about 4 mm**? And when looking closer, there is **another frequent jump of <1mm**:

[image: measured distances]

(As far as I can tell, the jumps increase at larger distances.)

**Is this an issue of how I read the sensor on the ESP32, or is it something happening internally on the HC-SR04?**

I'd love to understand the reason for this effect to be able to improve the accuracy of my measurements.

Comment: And how exactly are you calculating the distance?

Comment: @gre_gor: `double distance = duration * 0.03455` (I'll add it to my question.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's from the HC-SR04... it uses echos and it seems your bad readings are some kind of echo reflections.

What you should do is either remove the bad readings, or take the average/most common value of the last x readings.

Or throw away values too far off some default (like the last average) and average the rest.

Comment: Sure, I could implement some kind of filter. But actually I want to use it on a moving platform, so I can't repeat any measurement.

Comment: No, the spacing is much to small to be multiple reflections.  For that to occur, you'd be seeing multiples of the *base* reading, rather than a distribution around a basic value.